# How to access the first and last value of a view in java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

In Java a *view* is a lightweight object which implements the `Collection` or `Map` interface but is not a real collection. When we use `Map.values()` in Java we get a *view* of the values stored against keys in a `Map` interface. Like other collections in Java  a *view* also comes with `get()` and `set()` methods. I cannot find any hint to access the first or last value in a *view*. The `get()` method accepts a perimeter and searches for that perimeter and on finding that passed value it returns that. So is there a way through which one can get the first value of a Java *view*.

I tried to using `get()` method but I know that it doesn't looks at particular index it rather searches for the provided value in the `collection`.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question to change the formatting from `view` to *view* because while the concept exists there is no class/interface/... in there, so `view` is not represented in code anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** treat views like any other collection, there's nothing special about them being views. For some of them you can get the first/last. For others you can't. For all of them you can "fake" it by using iteration order (which may or may not be meaningful).

Whether or not a given view even *has* the concept of a first or last object depends on what it represents. A few representative examples are as follows:

- [`Map.keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) returns a `Set` because the order of keys in a `Map` is undefined and there can't be any duplicates
- [`Map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()) returns a `Collection` because the order of its values is undefined. It can also contain duplicates, so it can't be a `Set`.
- [`List.sublist()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) returns a `List` because it's simply a "zoomed in" view of a `List` so getting the first/last works just like any other.
- [`SortedSet.subSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet(E,E)) returns another `SortedSet` for reasons analogous to the `List`.

When the view happens to be a `List` then `l.get(0)` and `l.get(l.size()-1)` will return the first/last element respectively.

If the view is a `Collection` then there is no meaningful "first" or "last", because there's no defined order. You *could* use `iterator()` and designate the first value returned by `next()` as the "first" and the last one as "last", but that depends on the iteration order which is frequently undefined (plus iterating to the last element could be quite expensive).

Comment: Sorry for not being able to mark your answer as useful because of my reputation.

Comment: For completion: if your `Map` is a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html), you can call, e.g. [`navigableKeySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html#navigableKeySet()) to get a key set view that is a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) and hence, allows to efficiently get the first or last element. (In practice, all sorted maps are also navigable maps)

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying object is a `Collection` then there is no order: in Java, a `Collection` has no ordering, and so there is no concept of a first or last element.

You could sort the collection and then retrieve the first value instead.

Comment: Yes that's a nice way, I am writing solution to a problem, sorting would cost me another O(nlog n) complexity. I was willing to solve it with o(n) complexity.